# Is it possible add content add-in from Taskpane?

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

Is there any way to create web surface (content add-in) in excel workbook from taskpane or from custom toolbar button?
Currently i'm trying to make usage of my content add-in more user-friendly. I wonder is there any way to bypass standard procedure and spawn a copy of my content add-in in current workbook simply by clicking on custom toolbar button?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported way for doing that. It is not possible.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Thank you, Eugene. I found some debates on this functional back from 2018, thought it was already sorted out in some way.